# How to calculate day difference between today's date and date from doc but eliminating time from it in scripts of elastic search

Tags: java, php, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I tried this solution and it works but it takes time stamp also....I want to eliminate time stamp...

```
"filter": {
    "script": {
        "script": { 
            "inline":"(new Date().getTime() - doc['current_edd'].date.getMillis()) /
                            (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)  == params.missDelby",
             "params": { "missDelby": 1 }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean, i want to eliminate timestamp and what is the expected result of your query ?

Comment: So what i mean is, i want to find out the no of days between two dates... but the problem is my value is in yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss format... so i want to remove the HH:mm:ss from the dates while fetching records and calculate exact no. of days between now() & doc['dateval'].

Comment: I hope you understand my point....i was thinking of finding a way of removing or resetting the time i.e HH:mm:ss and then get the day difference between dates like sql's datediff() function.

Comment: You want to remove the time part from date, difference between 2019-12-04 11:00:00 and 2019-12-05 01:00:00 is 1 day ??

Comment: yes, you got it right...I only want to subtract the dates and eliminate time during calculation...I am having hard time finding solutions..My Elastic version is 5, and I want to do this in script tags...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can use some math to remove the time part with this simple calcul

```
long t1 = new Date().getTime();
t1 -= t1 % (24 * 3600 * 1000); //24 * 3600 * 1000 total milliseconds in a day
```

The you can update your query like this

```
"filter": {
    "script": {
        "script": { 
            "inline": "long t1 = new Date().getTime(); 
                       long t2 = doc['PostCodeDate'].value.getMillis(); 
                       t1 -= t1 % (24 * 3600 * 1000); 
                       t2 -= t2 % (24 * 3600 * 1000);
                       return (t1 - t2) / (24 * 3600 * 1000) == params.missDelby",
             "params": { "missDelby": 1 }
         }
     }
}
```

I'll update my solution as soon as I found a simpler approach.

Comment: I tried this in Elastic search and it works, but i dont understand why you added +1 in return statement..kindly explain that.

Comment: @AshaLodhi It's a mistake, I considered that between 2019-12-05 and 2019-12-06 for example there is 2 days, but in your case it just 1 day. I fixed it

Comment: thanks for the update...let me know if there is more elegant way of doing the same.Thanks alot!